# How do I make my page layout full-width

Tags: css

I 've looked all over the internet and I can't seem to find the answer: How can I make my wordpress theme into a full width layout instead of narrow down the middle?

Here's my website heatwaveenergydrink.com

I really cant figure this out. I've been at it all day.

Comment: add a `width:100%;` to your main wrapper

Comment: @Cʜᴜɴ I tried that, but the css seemingly contains no main wrapper

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect your code you'll find the answer there:

Change the width of `.dslc-modules-section-wrapper`

This class currently has a fixed width of 740px and houses your primary content.